# найти нужный текст в .bak файле 1С

Tags: 1с

Есть .bak (MS SQL SERVER) файл от 1С.
Как найти одну таблицу в этом файле?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Файл с расширением BAK является форматом резервного копирования. Можно попробовать восстановить его в 1С или sql management studio. Затем из восстановленной базы вытащить все необходимые данные.